# Sketching graph of $F(x)=\left(\frac{x-4}{4x}+\frac{x-12}{4x-16}-\frac{x+4}{4x-x^2}\right):\frac{1}{2x}$

Tags: functions, graphing-functions

> Sketch the graph of:$$F(x)=\left(\dfrac{x-4}{4x}+\dfrac{x-12}{4x-16}-\dfrac{x+4}{4x-x^2}\right):\dfrac{1}{2x}$$

So, we start with the domain: $D: x\ne0, x\ne 4; x\in(-\infty;0)\cup(0;4)\cup(4;+\infty).$ When I simplify, I get $F(x)=x-4.$ I am trying to sketch the graph of the function. By a theorem, point $A(0;-4)$ lies on it but in the domain $x\ne 0$. How should I make it?

Comment: Does the colon (:) in your formula mean division/ratio?

Comment: If you are talking about $:\dfrac{1}{2x}$, yes it does.

Comment: Also: You've got an $F.$ Then you say, "we start with the domain..." With what goal?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews, I am not sure I understand what you mean. We call a function a defined function when we also have its domain/range.

Comment: So you are trying to determine the domain and range?

Comment: I have already determined it. I am trying to sketch the graph of the function and I have some questions about this. That's why I made this post.

Comment: Your simplification tells you how to graph it. $F(x)=x-4$ when $x\neq 0,4.$ Surely, you know how to graph $G(x)=x-4$ define for all $x.$ Then the usual way to graph $F$ is to graph $G,$ but put circles instead of the values at $0,4.$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews, got it! Thanks!

Comment: Also very useful is to draw a graph with several online tools to understand some small errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your statements are correct, the graph should just be the straight line $F(x)=x-4$ with holes in the line corresponding to the points where $x=-4,0,4$  What theorem says $(0,-4)$ is on the graph?  As you say, the function is not defined at $x=0$.  You can the limit of the function as $x$ approaches each of these points and get a finite answer.  These are called removable singularities because you can "fill them in" to get a continuous function.

Comment: Thank you! I got it. And I think $x=-4$ is in the range.

Comment: $x$ is the domain.  $-4$ would be the function value at $x=0$, but it is not defined there, so $-4$ is not in the range of the function.